# Spectral Measures: Completeness

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Given a Borel space $\Omega$ and a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a spectral measure $E:\mathcal{B}(\Omega)\to\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$.

A spectral measure can be completed $\overline{E}$.

*(For details see: Birman & Solomyak, Section 5.2, Page 126-127)*

Now, it is crucially for many instances that its probability measures are complete then, too.

But this is to much to hope for...

So what can happen in worst case?